# jQuery or CSS - Center a floating div based on the center of another div

Tags: jquery, css, center

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu and I'm stuck trying to show the dropdown menu, under the parent link, in the center of it .

I'm looking to make the dropdown box have the same middle as the middle of the top element / parent element / the link above the dropdown menu .

The best that I got is using CSS margin to estimate the center but that seems like a bad idea.

Maybe a CSS solution is better then a jQuery solution, but I would consider either.

This is my header navigation menu :

```
<style>
    #nav li ul { margin:70px 0 0 -75px; width: 200px; position: absolute; z-index:99; }
</style>

<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="mitem mhome" title="">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="mitem mshop" title="">shop</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li class="mheader"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hard Drives</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Speakers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Equipment</a></li>
        </ul>            
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="mitem mdespre" title="">despre noi</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li class="mheader"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hard Drives</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Speakers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Equipment</a></li>
        </ul>             
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to build a horizontal menu with secondary-links that appear when you hover over the primary links.

As a basic example, you can start with the following CSS:

```css
#nav > li {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 200px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#nav > li > a {
    display: block;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 10px;
}
#nav > li > ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

When you mouse over the primary links, you can see the secondary menu.

You can see the demo  at:  http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/BrL3G/

You can do a lot of minor adjustments to the styling, but at least you have something to demonstrate the basic concepts.